# Some functions appear as undefined firebase/auth v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I was rewriting my code from firebase v8 to v9, i was watching [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#web-version-9_5)

i try to use the `signInWithRedirect()` function followed by the `getRedirectResult()` function

i import them like i import my others functions but when i `console.log()` thoses i get `undefined` in my console

here is my code :

```js
import { View } from "react-native";

import firebase, { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

import { GoogleAuthProvider, useDeviceLanguage, signInWithCredential, onAuthStateChanged, getAuth, signInWithRedirect, getRedirectResult } from "firebase/auth";

const LoginSceen = (props) => {

  console.log(signInWithRedirect) //return undefined
  console.log(getRedirectResult ) //return undefined
 
  console.log(getAuth) //return [Function getAuth]
  console.log(GoogleAuthProvider) //return [Function GoogleAuthProvider]
  

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#9297C4" }}>

    </View>
  );
}

export default LoginSceen;
```

PS : the error i get is `TypeError: _auth.signInWithRedirect is not a function`
firebase version in my package.json `"firebase": "^9.6.0",`

[here the getAuth function detected by vscode IntelliSense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vf7u.png)
[here the signInWithRedirect function who appear as undefined in my console but detected too by IntelliSense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFY1j.png)

Comment: I guess it's an expo compatibility problem but not sure, i try to move on vanilla react native and i will tell if it works

Comment: Finally no, have the same issue on vanilla react native, i have reported it on github here : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5837, i'll update the post when have an answer

Comment: Here the response i get from the Firebase team on my github isue : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5837#issuecomment-1005038520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no solution :** since

> React Native does not export the signInWIthPopup and
> signInWithReactNative entrypoints since both of these functions
> directly modify the DOM
>
> [by sam-gc](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5699#issuecomment-961263804)

And here the response i get from the Firebase team on my github isue : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5837#issuecomment-1005038520